# Angle Measurement

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image: Geometric problem with a triangle]
[image: Geometric problem with a triangle]

***What is the value of $x$ ?***

I know that it will be less than 20.

Comment: I like this problem, so I added a clearer picture

Answer (score 2):

[image: Solution]

Let $l$ be the line bisecting $\angle ACD$, and reflect the figure across this line. Notice that the reflection preserves $C$ and switches $A$ and $D$. Let $B'$ be the image of $B$ under this reflection.

Since $\triangle ABC$ is isoceles, with $\angle ACB = \angle ABC$ and $\angle BAC = 20^{\circ}$, it follows that $\angle ACB = 80^{\circ}$, and hence $\angle DCB' = 80^{\circ}$. Thus,
\begin{align} \angle ACD + \angle ACB + \angle BCB' + \angle DCB' &= 360^{\circ} \\\implies 140^{\circ} + 80^{\circ} + \angle BCB' + \angle 80^{\circ} &= 360^{\circ}\\\implies \angle BCB' &= 60^{\circ}.\end{align}
Now, $BC = B'C$ since $B'$ and $C$ are the images of $B$ and $C$ under the reflection. Hence, $\triangle BCB'$ is a triangle with $BC = B'C$ and $\angle BCB' = 60^{\circ}$, so it must be equilateral (by SAS congruency). Thus, $BB' = BC$. Since $AB = DB'$ due to reflection and $AB = CD$ by hypothesis, it follows that $CD = DB'$. Thus, by SSS congruence, we have $\triangle BCD\cong \triangle BB'D$, so $\angle CDB = \angle B'DB$. In particular, $\angle CDB$ bisects $\angle CDB'$. By reflection, $\angle CDB' = \angle CAB = 20^{\circ}$, so $\angle CDB = \boxed{10^{\circ}}$.

(Thanks to @zar for the picture!)

Comment: I like this syntethic proof. I will add a picture, if you don't mind.

Comment: @zar Please do! I would have added one myself if I had any skill in manipulating graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Lets first work out $|AD|$ using the isosceles triangle $ACD$:
\begin{align}
|AD|&=2z\sin(70°),\\
\end{align}
where I define $z\equiv |AB|=|AC|=|CD|$.

Form the isosceles triangle  $ABC$ we can work out  $|BC|:$
\begin{align}
|BC|&=2z\sin(10°).\\
\end{align}

For the triangle $ABD$ one now knows the angle at $A$ which is $20°+20°=40°$ and the two sides $|AB|=z$ and $|AD|$ from the equation above. One can calculate the missing side with the cosine law/rule:
\begin{align}
|BD|^2&=z^2 +(2z\sin(70°))^2-2z(2z\sin(70°))\sin(40°).\\
\end{align}
At last we can use the sine law/rule in the triangle $BCD$ to get $x$ using that the missing angle at $B$ is $360°-140°-80°=140°$:
\begin{align}
\frac{|BD|}{\sin(140°)}&=\frac{|BC|}{\sin(x)},\\
\sin(x)&=\frac{|BC|\sin(140°)}{|BD|},\\
\sin(x)&=\frac{\sin(10°)\sin(140°)}{\sqrt{1/4+\sin(70°)^2-\sin(70°)\sin(40°)}}.
\end{align}

This results in an angle $x\sim8.8°$, which looks plausible to me. I might have screwed up a factor two or a half at some point/angle but I am sure that this way works. There might be another way to get to this or to simplify the last equation but I stopped there.

Comment: Angle chasing shows that $\angle BCD = 140^\circ$, so that, by the Law of Sines in $\triangle BCD$, $$\frac{\sin x}{|\overline{BC}|} = \frac{\sin(40^\circ-x)}{|\overline{CD}|}$$ Thus, with $\sin 30^\circ = 1/2$, and your notation, we can write $$z \sin x = 2z\sin 10^\circ \sin(40^\circ-x) \quad\to\quad \sin 30^\circ \sin x = \sin(40^\circ-x) \sin 10^\circ$$  *By inspection*, $x=10^\circ$ is the desired solution, but the eqn can also be solved. (The [product-to-sum identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) help.)